# Migrate from TFS to VSS

Tags: tfs, visual-sourcesafe

I installed Team Foundation Server and migrated my code a year ago from VSS. It was a big mistake. Between workspaces, read-only flags, solution bindings and bad merge tools, I think I should have just stuck with VSS.

So, how do I migrate back to VSS from TFS?

Comment: +1 because I know he is joking. I hope.

Comment: @CAD bloke, why do you think he's joking? Both solutions are crappy, whether one is marginally less crappy in certain areas it's still a reasonable request to move between them

Comment: @Krzysztof Because nobody could be that crazy.

Comment: VSS is like not having version history at all! This makes migration easy: delete your source code.

Comment: @CAD bloke, well, let's just say - I know Paul ;)

Comment: @Krzysztof Me too. Perhaps we should check in on him. Check for scars.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Your issues may be resolved by the 2010 version.

Comment: The read-only flags, solution bindings and bad merge tools were sooooo much better in VSS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TFS has some nice^H^H^H^ awful APIs into the source control system. You could write a program that:

1. N = 1
2. Checks out the source as at ChangeSet N from TFS
3. Checks it into VSS reusing the comment field
4. N++, Goto 1

You'd lose the time and user info, but at least you'll have your history.

Not sure how it would scale, but you could temporarily put it into MongoDB or queue it up using BizTalk. Then get multiple computers to do the checkin operations. If you have one per user, and have them adjust their clocks, you could preserve that info.

Or you could cut off your arm, both have the same result.

Comment: Forgot to mention this method is CAHC approved

Answer (score 14):

VSS is the worst Version Control tool out there, please don't go back there. If TFS is *really* not your thing (and that's fair enough) then you should consider Subversion, or a DVCS such as Mercurial or git. If you like the simplicity of VSS then Sourcegear's "Vault" might be worth investigating. I've never used it in anger but it's very similar to VSS in layout and function, but it won't corrupt your code and die on it's arse if your repository goes over 2GB in size.

Another thing to note is that VSS is now out of mainstream support and wont be getting any more bug fixes or versions, from MS's point of view it's a dead product.

If you give some more detail then maybe someone can help you overcome the problems rather than going through the pain of migrating to another VCS?

For example the merge tools in TFS are a bit ropey but they can be [replaced by just about any other tool on the market](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmanning/archive/2006/02/20/diff-merge-configuration-in-team-foundation-common-command-and-argument-values.aspx), I use [SourceGear Diffmerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/) but there are plenty of others you can use.

I've never really had a problem with workspaces or solution bindings so without more information I can't really offer any help. As for Read Only flags, I assume you mean when you edit files outside of Visual Studio? If that's the case then the [TFS power tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f) can be used to install Explorer integration which will let you do the most common version control tasks without having to wait for Visual Studio to warm up.

[image: TFS with Windows Explorer]

I think TFS is a much better Version Control tool than VSS but that's a pretty low bar to be honest. Of course YMMV :-) just please try to avoid VSS at all costs!

Comment: +1 for the effort put into trying to reason with a crazy person

Answer (score 5):

Disconnect from Source Control for TFS, and then add then re-add to VSS, though surely you can come up with a much better solution than VSS? Subversion, Git, Mercurial, Veracity?

Comment: +1 for asking why the user wants to move back to VSS. I know everyone's heard it but I'll still quote it (dunno who said it) - "it is safer to print your source code, shred it and set it on fire than to put it in VSS".

Comment: Maybe it's "The devil you know is better than the devil you don't."

Comment: You could always use Hg to source control your VSS repository

Answer (score 4):

VSS is end of life. Why not use Hg or Git?

You can use vss2git to convert your history to a git repo and worse case use Hg to port the repo to Hg.